# Unity resolve with two different LifetimeManagers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container

This application exists, and likely has some less than ideal design decisions that we can't just change...so here goes.

In our Unity initializer, the following is registered

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

This is how the entire app gets it's context.  However, for the multithreaded code that was written for one part, this breaks it.  Changing it to this fixes it, but causes the rest of the app to be unreliable.

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyContext>(new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
```

The multithreaded code, is run using Commands, they are created with a CommandFactory, that creates a child container.

```
_container = container.CreateChildContainer();
```

Then this function resolves the command, injecting a new context because it's started on a new thread:

```
    public T CreateCommand<T>() where T : IProcessCommandBase
    {
        return _container.Resolve<T>();
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to use both Lifetime managers...one for the rest of the app, and another just in the command factory.

Ideas?

Comment: You can try using named instance in second case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209119/unity-to-resolve-by-name

Comment: Interesting problem. So basically you want a LifetimeManager that shares the behavior of both HierarchicalLifetimeManager and PerThreadLifetimeManager?